# How do you remove strong garlic odor from enclosed space (garage)?

Tags: garlic, dehydrating, smell

I dehydrated garlic in my garage a couple of days ago and now I need to remove the strong garlic odor in the garage -- any ideas?

I have left the garage door open for hours and have run the dehydrator with a bowl of white vinegar.

Comment: A couple warmish days with the garage door open should take care of the problem; perhaps a fan would help. Chemical/cleanser solutions would likely prove worse than the current smell issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you see advice to eat lemon, apples, or milk to eliminate garlic breath, it's the polyphenols in those things that break down the compounds in garlic that cause the smell. Tea, both green and black, is high in polyphenols. Try putting some strong green tea in a misting-type spray bottle and treating the air and the surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Leave some stale bread or biscuits, lime/lemon rind in the affected area.

Comment: *... thrown at your next door neighbour on the second Thursday of the month.* ^_^ Seriously, without instructions *what to do with the stuff* this answer is pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

Soak some cotton balls in Peppermint Oil(available @ Whole Foods Market) and leave in a disposable container in the Garage.  Replenish the oil as needed until odor is gone.  This oil is not extract, and it is not edible.

I had a dead squirrel in my attic (in an unreachable area) in the summer time and my house smelled soooooooo bad.  This dissipated the odor.  It took a few weeks, but it worked!  The garlic smell probably won't take that long to be gone.

You can also try leaving an OPEN bag of charcoal in the garage.  The charcoal will absorb the odor.

Answer (score -1):

try placing a few dishes of baking soda around your garage to absorb the odor.

Answer (score -2):

Park your car in the garage, the steel of the car will electrically attract the garlic odor.

Comment: I know that there's rubbing stainless steel on your hands to remove garlic smell there ... but I've never heard of it just needing to be nearby ... this might be one for testing (rub a few sealed containers w/ garlic, then place a fender washer in there, and leave it for a few days?)

Comment: Yeah so I am curious what Lisa tried and what worked.